# Using LINQ to Get Sum/ Average of a List with custom objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
public class PointD
{
    public double X
    { get; set; }
    public double Y
    { get; set; }

    public PointD(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y=y;
    }
   //operator for +,-, * and / are overridden
 }
```

Given a `list<PointD>`, how to get the average of it using LINQ? A `for` loop equivalent will be something like this:

```
  double xx, yy;
  for ( int i=0; i< ptlist.Count; i++)
     {
         xx+=ptlist[i].X;
         yy+=ptlist[i].Y; 
     }
  return new PointD(){X=xx, Y=yy};
```

You can use any **built-in** LINQ function only. You can't define an extension that takes care of this function.

Any idea?

**Edit: Of course, you can use two separate `Sum` extension method to Sum for X and Y component before merging them. But this is not what I want. What I want is a single query/ method that does the job**

Comment: wouldn't two sums work? Something like ptlist.Sum(p => p.X); and ptlist.Sum(p => p.Y);

Comment: "how to get the average of it using LINQ?"..I think you mean the sum

Comment: @the_ajp: it can work, but I want to put everything in one query, that's just it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Aggregate` function would come in handy here.

```
var sum = list.Aggregate((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
var average = list.Aggregate((acc, cur) => acc + cur) / list.Count;
```

Just insure that you have the `/` operator defined for types `PointD` and `int`, and this should do the job.

Note: I'm not quite sure whether you want the sum or average here (your question is somewhat ambiguous about this), but I've included examples for both.

Comment: PointD is a reference type, so depending on how the operators are implemented you may very well get an ArgumentNullException or NullReferenceException here. Possibly worth providing a non-null seed to the accumulator.

Comment: This is a good one, but I don't quite understand why I couldn't think of it.. duh!!

Comment: @Greg Beech: That's a fair point. I automatically assumed it was a `struct` (as the `Point` type in WPF/System.Drawing) is, but it seems he defined it as a class.
@Ngu Soon Hui: I recommend you define your `PointD` type as a `struct`, unless you have good reason otherwise. `Aggregate` will then use `default(PointD)` as the seed, which means things will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use the `Aggregate` method instead so you can provide your own aggregation function (`Sum` is just a convenient specialized case of this method). Something like:

```
points.Aggregate(new PointD(0, 0), (a, p) => a + p);
```

I know you say you don't want any additional methods defined, but if this is a common operation I'd be inclined to write an extension method for this, i.e.

```
public static PointD Sum(this IEnumerable<PointD> source)
{
    return source.Aggregate(new PointD(0, 0), (a, p) => a + p);
}
```

Because it's much more readable to be able to write:

```
points.Sum();
```

Comment: If he's already overloaded the operators for `PointD`, there's no need to redefine addition.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the `new PointD(0, 0),`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Fact]
    public void CanAddManyPointDs()
    {
        var points = new[]{
            new PointD( 1,1),
            new PointD( 2,3),
            new PointD( 3,4),
        };

        var result = points.Aggregate((p1, p2) => new PointD(p1.X + p2.X, p1.Y + p2.Y));
        Assert.Equal(result.X,6);
        Assert.Equal(result.Y,8);
    }
```