# Alternative to Linq Average method in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know an alternative way to write this code without using a Linq Method Average().

```
   double[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 0 };
        double average1 = array1.Average();
        Console.WriteLine(average1);
```

Comment: If you think this question is too trivial please do not down vote, I'm a beginner at programming in C#. Many thanks,

Comment: You haven't said why. And the alternative would be too just sum them all up and divide by length of the array, of course.

Comment: Try the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136013/using-linq-to-get-sum-average-of-a-list-with-custom-objects?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why you wouldn't want to use the LINQ Average function but you could loop through the elements of the array in order to calculate the sum and finally divide by the number of elements:

```
double[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 0 };
double average1 = 0;
foreach (var item in array1)
{
    average1 += item;
}
average1 = average1 / array1.Length;
Console.WriteLine(average1);
```

Now that you look at this code it is clear why the following is much better:

```
double[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 0 };
double average1 = array1.Average();
Console.WriteLine(average1);
```

Answer (score 4):

The question kind of vague, but some alternatives:

```
double average2 = array1.Sum() / Array.Length;
```

or

```
double sum = 0;
foreach(var item in array1)
{
   sum += item;
}
double average2 = sum / array1.Length;
```

Comment: This answer is good, it's silly to use `Count()` when the `Length` property can be used.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a concise answer that doesn't involve any LINQ methods (though why you'd restrict yourself to this, beats me):

```
double[] arr = new[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
double avg = 0;
Array.ForEach(arr, x => avg += x)
avg = avg / arr.Length;
```