# Linq getting average on a property of a List<class>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List. Coordinate has X, Y and Z that are double properties. I need to calculate the average of X, the average of Y and the average of Z.

```
   public class Coordinate
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Every example I can see is returning the average of a Collection or List of a simple double. How would the average of a property of a List be returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to Get Sum/ Average of a List with custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136013/using-linq-to-get-sum-average-of-a-list-with-custom-objects)

Comment: Do you want to average the values of X,Y,Z separately across the list or the average "average coordinate" of the list?

Comment: Separate average for x, y and z. I have a cloud of 3d points and need the central point of that cloud. Not sure how the average of all three rolled into one would do for me?

Comment: @EricSnyder look at my answer, the second part should be what you want (x = average of X'es, ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the average of each pont X,Y,Z in a list you can do it like this:

```
List<double> Averages = Coordinates.Select(c=> (c.X + c.Y + c.Z)/3).ToList();
```

If you want a single coordinate that its X is the average of X'es and ... then:

```
Coordinate cordinate = new Coordinate
{
     X = Coordinates.Average(c => c.X),
     Y = Coordinates.Average(c => c.Y),
     Z = Coordinates.Average(c => c.Z)
};
```

Comment: question is not clear enough but it doesn't seem to me to be what OP wants

Comment: @GiladGreen you are right its not clear, but having "need to calculate the averages of X, Y and Z" and as its a list of coordinates, I assumed he wants this. OP should clarify his question otherwise.